# Unset bash variables referring to non-existent directories

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bash-scripting

I have a file which is sourced by an application, adding relevant directories to $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

This is fine, but it results in somewhat excessive pollution of the $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, since quite a few paths are added, about 2/3 of which don't exist.

I can test for the existence of the directory using `[ ! -d $VARIABLE_TO_ADD_TO_PATH ]`, but if I find the directory doesn't exist, unsetting it seems to be harder.

I can write (for each of maybe 10 variables)

```
if [ ! -d $VAR ]
    unset VAR
fi
```

but I'd rather have a function.

I tried:

```
_testPathAndUnset()
{
   while [ $# -ge 1 ]
   do
      dirToTest=${1/startPattern/\$startPattern}
      if [ ! -d $dirToTest ]
         unset $1
      fi
      shift
   done
}
```

passing in values in a form like `_testPathAndUnset VAR1 VAR2 VAR3` (not `$VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3`), but now I have strings which don't expand.

Using `eval` might solve this for me, but other questions, answers, websites etc etc suggest this is generally a bad idea.

How can I solve this problem in a better way than 30 lines of 10x3 ?

```
if [ ! -d $VAR ]
    unset VAR
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function:

```
_testPathAndUnset() { for d in "$@"; do [ -d "${!d}" ] || unset "$d"; done; }
```

Here it is in use.  To start with, we have two directories:

```
$ ls -d */
a1/  a2/
```

We define four shell variables which may or may not evaluate to directories:

```
$ one=a1; two=a2; three=a3; four=a4
```

Now, run our function against those four variables:

```
$ _testPathAndUnset one two three four
```

And, observe that only two variables remain set:

```
$ echo "one=$one two=$two three=$three four=$four"
one=a1 two=a2 three= four=
```

Details:

- `for d in "$@"`

  This loops over every argument on the command line.
- `[ -d "${!d}" ] || unset "$d"`

  Here `d` refers to the name of a variable.  `${!d}` refers to the value of the variable named `d`.  This tests if the value of the variable named `d` is a directory.  If it is not, the `[` test evaluates to false and the `unset "$d"` clause is executed.

Comment: Perfect - thank you. The explanation is also very helpful.